# Tkinter Elements Not Responsive

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

It's me again. I want to make my window responsive and did a quit search. Everywhere it was the same answer `grid_columnconfigure(1,weight=1)`. But in my case, it's not working, please help!

This is the code I'm using [Edited]

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Entry, Text, Button, PhotoImage

from tkinter import font


from build import main

OUTPUT_PATH = Path(__file__).parent
ASSETS_PATH = OUTPUT_PATH / Path("./assets")


def relative_to_assets(path: str) -> Path:
    return ASSETS_PATH / Path(path)

window = Tk()

window.geometry("1440x1024")
window.configure(bg = "#FFFFFF")



canvas = Canvas(
    window,
    bg = "#FFFFFF",
    height = 1024,
    width = 1440,
    bd = 0,
    highlightthickness = 0,
    relief = "ridge"
)

canvas.place(x = 0, y = 0,relwidth=1, relheight=1)

subtext = canvas.create_text(
    343.0,
    179.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="What made you here?",
    fill="#000000",
    font=("Roboto Condensed", 89 * -1),


)
```

And what I want is to make Text and other widgets be **in size** when the window is resized, I don't know how to explain. It's just like in file explorer when resizing. Hope you get it

For now, it look like this when resizing -
[image]
Please help, sorry for bad English and Thanks in advance.

Comment: `grid_rowconfigure()` applies on widgets using `grid()`, but you use `place()` on `canvas()`.

Comment: Ouch, but what is used for `place()`

Comment: Use `canvas.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)`.

Comment: Not work, any alternatives?

Comment: What do you mean by *"not work"*?

Comment: you don't show all code but maybe you have some long-running code which blocks all `tkinter` and elements can't responsive - and this problem have nothing to do with this part of code.

Comment: maybe better describe what you means `responsive`. We can't run this code and we can't read in your mind - you have to describe all details. What do you do? Resize window, etc.? What result do expect? What result do you get?

Comment: if you want to move text when you resize window then `canvas` is wrong idea. `grid` can change size of canvas but it doesn't rescale it and doesn't move text on it. You would have to write all code on your own.

Comment: Edited the question with full code, please take a look, Thanks!

Comment: tkinter (and probably all other GUIs) don't scale widgets if window is too small to display all of them. They only organize free space when window is bigger then all widgets. And `Canvas` doesn't have function to automatically scale widgets or move them to keep them in middle of window. You could add i.e `red` baground to windows to see where is end of canvas and other widgets.

Comment: Got it! But i can make it non-resizable by setting a fixed geometry but do you know how to make the geometry fits any screen?

Comment: Use `window.state('zoomed')` instead of `window.geometry(...)`.